# How do I convert an XML file for use in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am trying to load [an XML file](http://www.cafeconleche.org/examples/baseball/1998statistics.xml) to fit into a Rails application and am having very little success.

I am thinking that I should use Nokogiri to parse the data.  The end goal here is to take the data from the link above, baseball stats, and have a table displaying its data, the baseball players stats and fit this into a Rails application.

Basically, it's two parts:

1. Reading the XML file into your program
2. Converting the XML into a hash, or any other suggestion

I am using Rails 4.0, Ruby 2.0, on Mac OSX.

How do I read the XML file and convert the data to allow it to run in a Rails application?

Comment: What is now exactly your question?

Comment: how do I read the xml file and convert the data to allow it to run in a ruby on rails application?

Comment: do you have any code snippets yet? or should we find the complete solution for you? :)

Comment: no code snippets yet.  am new, so am having trouble finding a good starting place.  thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? We need to know, and see your attempt. Otherwise it really seems like you are just fishing for code hoping someone will write it for you.

Comment: wasn't my intent.  just a newbie looking for guidance on an elegant starting place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For basic parsing an xml file you can read the tutorial and
  documentation of Nokogiri:
  http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html.
- There is also a little cheatsheet for nokogiri:
  https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet
- There is also a railscast about it. But this railscast is about
  parsing a html document. But it helps you to understand the basics:
  http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri

Comment: this is perfect.  thanks.  quick question.  where in a rails app would the xml file be saved

Comment: It is not necessary to save the XML File. You only want the content of these file. You can write a rake task to import the xml content and save it to your database. If you want to parse the xml file and display it every time if the user go to your app, you can implement the parsing part in the controller or in a helper.

Comment: You shouldn't parse and display at every request if the XML hasn't changed. Parse it once and load it into the database or extract the needed data and store that in a YAML or JSON file. Reloading either of those would be faster than reparsing the XML. It's important to think ahead; What would be the fastest if your site/page gets hit a lot?

Comment: To parse the XML file on every request is only a simple way to parse a XML file that changed frequently.

Comment: thanks you guys.  got the program up and running.  appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

I would use Nokogiri for this task. Take a look at Ryan Bates RailsCasts "[Screen Scraping with Nokogiri](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri)".

In case of XML it will look very similar, just use `Nokogiri::XML` in place of `Nokogiri::HTML`. Check [the Nokogiri documentation](http://nokogiri.org/) - read the main page carefully.

Comment: for a rails application, where would you put the XML file and where would you put the code for Nokogiri to do its parsing.

Comment: As @Mindbreaker said, you can read the file straight from the Internet and use rake task with Nokogiri code to parse the XML file and populate your database. Again some help from Ryan about writing rake task for this purpose: http://railscasts.com/episodes/126-populating-a-database

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'nokogiri' #You need nokogiri gem

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("file_name.xml")) #Open your xml file
```

## now you can access the value in xml by

doc.xpath('tag name')

## for the text value

doc.xpath('tag name').text

EXAMPLE

## To print name and id

```
xml_str = <<EOF 
<root>
  <thing>
    <id>1234</id>
    <name>The Name1</name>
  </thing>
  <thing>
    <id>2234</id>
    <name>The Name2</name>
  </thing>
</root>
EOF
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_str)
doc.xpath('root').xpath('thing').each do |v|
   puts v.xpath('id').text
   puts v.xpath('name').text
end
```